# Why is New York City also called "the Big Apple"?

Tags: etymology, nouns, adjectives, proper-nouns, nicknames

I have heard many times people say *the Big Apple* to mean *New York City*.

What is the origin of this nickname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia offers some [interesting reading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Apple) on the subject, but my understanding is that nobody still knows for sure.

> The earliest citation for "big apple" is the 1909 book *The Wayfarer in New York*, by Edward Martin, writing: "Kansas is apt to see in New York a greedy city. . . . It inclines to think that the big apple gets a disproportionate share of the national sap". [The American journalist] William Safire considered this the coinage, but the Random House Dictionary of American Slang considers the usage "metaphorical or perhaps proverbial, rather than a concrete example of the later slang term", and [Barry] Popik [, an American amateur etymologist,] likewise does not consider this the coinage.

Comment: Another [interesting read](http://salwen.com/apple.html).

Answer (score 2):

Apples are commonly grown in New York State. It is the state fruit and a major export.

So, *Big Apple* would compare the city to upstate. Imagine a map with the cities marked as apples.

Comment: I believe yours is the true, but "unprovenable" answer. I think it started off by some people marking various cities on a NY map with the apple icon, and NYC was marked with the biggest and most prominent apple.